# Angular: ViewContainer isn't inserting component adjacent to anchor element, but nesting within the component itself

Tags: angular, dynamic, tabs, transclusion, angular2-ngcontent

I have created a tab view, with the following structure:

```
<tabs>
        <ul #getVCRefHERE >
            <li>tab1</li>
            <li>tab2</li>
        </ul>

        <tab>
            <ng-content></ng-content> <!--screen for tab2 -->
        </tab>
        <tab>
            <ng-content></ng-content> <!--content for tab1 -->
        </tab>
</tabs>
```

I create each component: tabs,tab,and the component placed in the ng-content.  place. The issue is when I insert at the end of the ViewContainer(it uses ul as it's anchor element) the sequential tabs are nest inside of the tab like this:

```
<tabs>
            <ul #postionVCRef>
                <li>tab1</li>
                <li>tab2</li>
            </ul>

            <tab>
                <ng-content></ng-content> <!--screen for tab1 -->
                <tab>
                    <ng-content></ng-content> <!--content for tab2 -->
                </tab>
            </tab>

    </tabs>
```

It is fancy trick, but not helpful. When I insert at position 0 this weird nesting doesn't occur, but the tabs are inserted in opposite order than they were created which causes me issues later in my app.

The code that creates the tab with its projectable node looks like this:

```
// Tab == SubContainer,  Tabs == Container
    makeComp(component: Type<DynamicComponent>){
        let compFactory =this.compFR.resolveComponentFactory(component);
        let compRef = this.viewContainer.createComponent(compFactory);

        let length =this.viewContainer.length - 1;
        console.log(length)
        let subFactory = this.compFR.resolveComponentFactory(SubContainer); 
        let subRef = this.viewContainer.createComponent(subFactory,length,undefined,[[compRef.location.nativeElement]]);
        subRef.instance.title = compRef.instance.name;
        this.subList.push(subRef.instance);

      }
```

I feel the issue is probably in how I am creating the ng-content(projectable nodes). Unfortunately, I am unaware why the viewContainer appears to be using the tab's ng-content as the anchor element to insert the next tab.

I would really appreciate someone with better understanding of viewContainer to tell me why this might be occurring. Here is my sample [app](http://plnkr.co/edit/O9SeweZGRBbC5zSGxhRV?p=preview) demonstrating this nesting behavior.

Comment: I don't understand what the expected behavior is.

Comment: Adding a component dynamically adds it as sibling to the element that is used as `ViewContainerRef`. If you want the dynamically added comonent be a sibling of  `<li>tab2</li>`, then this is the element where you need to add `#getVCRefHERE`

Comment: I just want the tab to inserted in the correct order,appended to the end when created.

Comment: What is the "correct order"? What is "end when created"?

Comment: Yes, see what you are saying, I don't necessarily need tab to be a sibling with li, it is fine if it is siblings with ul. I just need each tab to be put in the correct order like this.  ul ,tabContent1,tabContent2,tabContent3

Comment: The end is ViewContainerRef.length - 1 or at the end of the viewContainer. I can currently prepend, but I want to append to the viewContainer.

Comment: Sounds like this could be demonstrated with 1/3 of the code you have in the Plunker. This would make it easier to discuss what the expected behavior is and how the actual behavior deviates from that.

Comment: If I append the tab the subquential tabs will be nested inside each other. Ok I will reduce the code to make it easier. I have to run to a meeting. I'll put updated plnk soon

Comment: As you use the same `viewContainerRef` and insert `sub-container` in previous index then angular will take content node(`drop-down` on first step) as sibling element after that your new `sub-container` will be placed. You can avoid it by using different `ViewContainerRef`'s http://plnkr.co/edit/eqLXZDAxqTwi784eBANc?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui you never cease to amaze me, that is exactly what I needed. I just need you to elaborate on one part of your statement. "You can avoid it by using different ViewContainerRef's", I see you inject a vcRef and use it to make the component, and then use the other viewContainer to make the SubContainer. My question is aren't these two vcRefs referring to the same location? What makes it different using two vs one if they are referring to the same spot? If you could put this as your answer that would be really helpful and I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code to insert siblings of element where you apply selector of component. 
At your component:

```
import { HostListener,ComponentRef,EventEmitter,OnInit,ElementRef, Injectable ,Component,Input,Output,ViewContainerRef,ViewChild  } from '@angular/core';
```

At constructor

```
    constructor(private _vcr: ViewContainerRef,private _eref: ElementRef) {
}
```

At class

```
@ViewChild('Date') Date;
ngAfterViewInit() {
       this._vcr.createEmbeddedView(this.Date);  
    }
```

at template

```
<ng-template #Date>
// Your Html
</ng-template>
```

The natural behavior of using child selector is to insert the code of child  template html inside the selector tags which are used in parent component. So we have to use createEmbeddedView function of ViewContainerRef [ Parent HTML Element]. If you want to provide some html with in selector tag fro parent to child then use  inside child template.