# Angular 2 : Validate child component form fields from the parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular-validation

**Problem statement :**

Parent component having `<form>` tag and some `<input>` tags inside it, and child component also have some `<input>` tags, parent component has one `<submit>` and we are validating form fields on submit the form.

How to validate the child component `<input>` fields from parent component on `submit` the form ?

**Requirement :**

If a parent component has a form containing child components with `input` components in their template, then these `input` components should be validate on click if submit from the parent component.

**Findings :**

There are lot of posts in SO having same problem statement but did not find any suitable solution.All the below posts validate the whole form but my requirement is to validate each field in child component.

- [Angular 2 validation together with the child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955606/angular-2-validation-together-with-the-child-component#)
- [Allow template-driven form inputs across a component hierarchy to register with a single parent form](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9600)
- [How to check the validity of the child component form within the parent component in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47550917/how-to-check-the-validity-of-the-child-component-form-within-the-parent-componen)

Comment: Use model driven form. Because it will check model values not form names of input.

Comment: I had a very similar requirement, but quite more complex because I had to validate a hierarchy forms, children, nested components and so on.  It is very easy to validate using Reactive forms approach https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: Are you facing problem with plugins, like auto-complete or datepiker?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47695731/4834833 read this. Here a piece of code which added after a given parent element. I  hope something help you.

Comment: Can you post a sample application so we can have more context?

Comment: @mukundpatel I achieve that using template driven technique as well . please look into the solution.

Comment: Nice use. I get more information from your given solution. It is a good chaining of events.

Comment: @DanielC. I tried to achieve that using template driven forms technique. please look into my solution. It is working like a champ. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We can achieve it using `template driven` technique as well. Find below the steps **:**

- From parent component to child component we have to pass submit button event.

  ```
  <button type="button" (click)="enterForm(parentForm)">Submit</button>
  ```

  Here, `parentForm` is the form reference.
- call child component method using @ViewChild decorator from parent to pass `submit button event` on click of submit.

  ```
  @ViewChild('validateChildComponentForm') private ChildComponent: ChildComponent;
  ```
- Pass the reference of child form using @ViewChild decorator into the child component.

  ```
  @ViewChild('smartyStreetForm') form;

  enterForm(parentForm) {
      this.submitted = true;
      this.ChildComponent.validateChildForm(this.submitted);
      if(!parentForm.valid || !this.childFormValidCheck) {
          return;
      } else {
         // success code comes here.
      }                
  }
  ```
- Now in child component method we will check that if parent form is submitted and child component form is valid then emit true otherwise false into the parent component. we will use @Output decorator to emit the `isChildFormValid` value into the parent component.

  ```
  @Output() isChildFormValid: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  public validateChildForm(data: any) {
      if (data === true) {
          if(this.form.valid === true) {
              this.isChildFormValid.emit(true);
          } else {
              this.isChildFormValid.emit(false);
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Now in parent component we will get the isChildFormValid value.

  ```
  private isChildFormValid(formValid: any) {
      this.childFormValidCheck = formValid;
  }
  ```

**Pictorial representation :**

[image]

Comment: A lot of code to achieve this. feels like this should be more simple.

Comment: Can you please provide your more simple solution as an answer in this post.

Comment: Well I actually didn't have one... I was just saying it should be more simple. Although I am currently reading through this article that looks rather promising.

Comment: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html#understanding-controlvalueaccessor

Comment: but where are error messages at the bottom of the fields?